# Can't understand Error in XAML Converter

Tags: wpf, double, converters

I use a Converter to "convert" a Width. I want to make 10% of the "Parent" Width. So I use the Parameter Value "0.1" (10%). But in the Converter this Value will be converted to "1.0". I dont know why (see Picture below).

### PercentageConverter.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    namespace ErdBuilder.Shell.Converter
    {
        public class PercentageConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value,
                Type targetType,
                object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                double dblValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
                double dblParameter = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
                double val = dblValue*dblParameter;
                return val;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value,
                Type targetType,
                object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

### CoreStyles.xaml

```
    ...
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:ErdBuilder.Shell.Converter"
    ...
    <converter:PercentageConverter x:Key="PercentageConverter" />
    ...
    <Border x:Name="TrackRectangle" Height="15">
        <Border Background="SteelBlue" Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter},ElementName=TrackRectangle,Path=ActualWidth,ConverterParameter=0.1}"/>
    </Border>
```

### I dont understand this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this solution - error in interpreting the correct delimiter (have to replace '.' against ','):

### PercentageConverter.cs

```
    double dblParameter = System.Convert.ToDouble(((string)parameter).Replace('.',','));
```

instead of

```
    double dblParameter = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
```

Comment: The problem is your CultureInfo. The culture you have set interprets ',' as the decimal separator.

Comment: How can I change the CultureInfo ?